# strange behaviour in php date

Tags: php, date

A simple code to print a date

```
$first_date = 1319493600;
$last_date = 1320184800;

$testDate = $first_date;


while ($testDate<=$last_date)
{
    echo strftime("%a", $testDate).' '. strftime("%d", $testDate).' '.strftime("%b", $testDate).'<br>';
    $testDate += 86400;
}
```

Yes this simple script fails me as you see below

```
Tue 25 Oct
Wed 26 Oct
Thu 27 Oct
Fri 28 Oct
Sat 29 Oct
Sun 30 Oct <----Error
Sun 30 Oct <----Error
Mon 31 Oct
Tue 01 Nov
```

Anyone has any idea why?

Comment: This is indeed interesting. Did you try perhaps , $testDate = strtotime('+1 day', $testDate); ?

Comment: Also, is using date("D d M", $testDate) instead of strftime outputs the same text?

Comment: That code is working fine for me, wondering ...

Comment: @dev: you're on the right track.. :)

Comment: i get the correct result on my devbox using php5.3.6, have you set the `Default timezone`?

Comment: @dev, are you in the USA? You finished DST a week or two back, didn't you? In the UK, and the rest of Europe, we change back this weekend, the night of 29th/30th.

Comment: @Shai Mishali Your approach is correct. +1 day works better. As others have said here, never increase day by 24 hours.

thank you all guys - a helpfull lesson this was for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is, in fact, the reason why you should never increment the day by adding 24 hours to the timestamp. Chances are that you are in a timezone that observes daylight saving time and the last Sunday of October is not 24 hours long.

You can confirm this by adding `echo strftime("%r %x", $testDate);` inside the loop. (Also note that you can use multiple modifiers in `strftime()` so you don't have to concatenate them: `strftime("%a %d %b", $testDate);`.)

Always use date functions like `strtotime()` or `mktime()` to increment the date.

Comment: you are correct. $testDate = strtotime('+1 day', $testDate); works best.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's related to [DST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time#Procedure).. clocks are changed on the last sunday of october, in this year Sun 30 Oct.

Note: you also have to be in the "right" timezone for this to happen, eg here it's:

```
 # date -ud@1319493600
 Mon Oct 24 22:00:00 UTC 2011
```

so that one hour doesn't make any difference, but for you it does. This can be quite annoying as people won't be able to reproduce your problem :)

Comment: DST problem it is.
I am in greece - we change our time on sun 30, oct.

Answer (score 2):

This probably has to do with the daylight savings time change on 30 Oct. Try running the script with the times printed out too to see the change. Here's an example in my timezone:

```
php > $first_date = 1319493600;
php > $last_date = 1320184800;
php >
php > $testDate = $first_date;
php >
php >
php > while ($testDate<=$last_date)
php > {
php {     echo strftime("%a", $testDate).' '. strftime("%d", $testDate).' '.strftime("%b", $testDate). '(' . strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", $testDate) . ")\n";
php {     $testDate += 86400;
php { }
Mon 24 Oct(24.10.2011 23:00:00)
Tue 25 Oct(25.10.2011 23:00:00)
Wed 26 Oct(26.10.2011 23:00:00)
Thu 27 Oct(27.10.2011 23:00:00)
Fri 28 Oct(28.10.2011 23:00:00)
Sat 29 Oct(29.10.2011 23:00:00)
Sun 30 Oct(30.10.2011 22:00:00)
Mon 31 Oct(31.10.2011 22:00:00)
Tue 01 Nov(01.11.2011 22:00:00)
```

Answer (score 0):

On my machine the output is:

```
root@ubuntu:~# php /tmp/tst.php
Mon 24 Oct
Tue 25 Oct
Wed 26 Oct
Thu 27 Oct
Fri 28 Oct
Sat 29 Oct
Sun 30 Oct
Mon 31 Oct
Tue 01 Nov
root@ubuntu:~# php -v
PHP 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: May  2 2011 23:18:30)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

what `PHP` version are you using?

Also, it might have something to do with daylight savings - try printing the hours too

Comment: XAMPP 1.7.4 [PHP: 5.3.5]
My error as it seems was the $testDate += 86400; part of code.
$testDate = strtotime('+1 day', $testDate); works best.